# Overriding class method in ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to override a method from another gem. The code looks something like this:

```
module DatabaseCleaner
  class Base
    def orm_strategy(strategy)
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

In my gem:

```
require 'database_cleaner/base'

module DatabaseCleaner
  class Base
    def orm_strategy(strategy)
      # New code
    end
  end
end
```

However, it the original is still being used. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you include the original module first?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira ya just a typo in here

Comment: @NiklasB. Ya I included the original module file location

Comment: @Major: Hard to tell without more information. The concept is correct.

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm attempting to make a temporary gem that extends the functionality of databasecleaner until my code is integrated into the gem itself (if it is if not I'll have the code I need anyways). To do so though there's a line in DBcleaner that's causing problems because it's doing a require and the path is specific to the DBcleaner gem so I'm trying to override it to make it work with my new gem. I can post the code if that'd help...

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to override an **instance method** of the `Foo::Bar` class. You have to redefine the class's method:

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    def self.test  # self == Bar
      # New code
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If the original code looks like described in the question, OP in fact wants to override an instance method.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't resolve the problem. Still hitting the old function.

Comment: @Major, could you add `p DatabaseCleaner::Base.instance_method(:orm_strategy)` after the `require` call and immediately after the class definition, then tell us the output?

Comment: @MatheusMoreira so:
    `require 'database_cleaner/base'
    p DatabaseCleaner::Base.instance_method(:orm_strategy) after the require

    module DatabaseCleaner
        class Base
        end
        p DatabaseCleaner::Base.instance_method(:orm_strategy) after the require
    end`
correct or did I read that wrong?